# Excel getting current directory in Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, directory, path, powerquery

I have been trying to get current directory into Power Query. But it somehow doesn't work. How can I get current directory, to make the path dynamic for my Query, so that in case the file moved a new directory, I will have no issue with retrieving data into Power Query. Here is the code I tried with:

```
let

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="pathTable"]}[Content],

#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Path", type text}}),

Path = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","\[PathForSummaryFiles.xlsx]Path","\summary.xlsx",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Path"})

GetFilesFromFolder = Folder.Files(Path)

in

GetFilesFromFolder
```

the code above throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

In excel, name a cell **DirectoryRangeName** using formulas ... name manager

Within that cell, put in a formula to capture the path of that file

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
```

or enter your own path such as:

```
c:\directory\subdirectory\
```

Then, once in powerquery, read that value, and combine however you want to reference it such as

```
let Directory =  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DirectoryRangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Directory & "abs.xlsx"), null, true)
in  Source
```

Or

```
let Directory =  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DirectoryRangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
GetFilesFromFolder = Folder.Files(Directory)
in GetFilesFromFolder
```

Instead of a formula in the range name, you could simply put a full filepath such as **c:\temp\a.xlsx**

and then read it within powerquery

```
let FilePath=  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DirectoryRangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FilePath), null, true)
in  Source
```

Comment: Thank you, the most part of your code did work very well, with only entering the formula =CELL("filename"), but if I try with this one: =LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1).

I get the following Error: 

There's a problem with this formula.

Not trying to type a formula?

When the first charcter is an equal(=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula.
you type: =1=1, cell shows : 2
To get around this, type an apostrophe (') first:
you type: '=1=1, cell shows: =1+1 .

Do you have any idea solving this issue ?

Comment: I did not suggest cell(“file name”) I suggested CELL("filename",A1). Did you copy my formula correctly?  And it is a formula and starts with a =

Comment: yes, exactly I just copied it and got that error. It just works with this formula : =cell(“file name”). In other all cases I get the same error.